# Uploading zip file with POST/httpwebrequest in C#

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, zip

I'm trying code from http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2009/12/16/posting-multipartform-data-using-.net-webrequest.aspx to do a POST through httpwebrequest.

If I try this same code with a text file, it's fine.  However if I do it with a zip file, then when re-download that file it's saying it's not a valid zip.  I assume the zip portion is likely getting uploaded as text rather than binary.  However, that page does say " It's OK to include binary content here. Don't base-64 encode it or anything, just stream it on in."  But this doesn't seem to be working with the given code.  I'm assuming I have to change the portion that reads the file to the stream:

```
  using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(file.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
  {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
    {
      stream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    fileStream.Close();
  }
```

Maybe to use BinaryReader?  I'm a bit confused on how to use that in this context though, or if it's even what I need to do.  A nudge in the right direction would be awesome.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BinaryReader should work indeed:

```
FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(file.FullName);
// 
long numBytes = fInfo.Length;

FileStream fStream = new FileStream(file.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fStream);

byte[] bdata = br.ReadBytes((int)numBytes);

br.Close();

fStream.Close();

// Write bdata to the HttpStream
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("url-here");
// Additional webRequest parameters settings.
HttpStream stream = (Stream)webRequest.GetRequestStream();
stream .Write(bdata, 0, bdata.Length);
stream.Close();

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebRewponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Hmmm....still getting a non-valid file after download.  Do I have to set an encoding method for my httpwebrequest?  I was under the impression I didn't have to, since I was sending a stream, but...

Comment: Sorry - new to this, and it's all a bit confusing.  :-/

Comment: Did you set options like  method type, content type , accept etc. on the webRequest?

Comment: 2/3 - method=post, contenttype=multipart/form-data (with the boundary).  All works fine with non-binary files.  Not accept, though, so maybe I need to specify zips in there?  I'll peek at the syntax now, then try and report back.  :-)

Comment: Set accept to */*, which as I understand it is wildcard - zip is still mangled.

Comment: No errors - the whole thing is in a try/catch and completes fine, and the form gives a "thank you" and processes.  Also of note: the bad version of the file is about 2-3 times bigger than the original, and completely different contents, so it's not just getting cutoff or anything easy...:-)

Comment: Oops - it stripped out the asterisks from either side of the slash in my "accept" comment above.  :-)  Asterisk slash asterisk.

Comment: Can you give me some more info, where are you uploading to file to (wcf service or a website)?

Comment: A form on a website.  I can go to the form itself through a browser and upload the same file into the same field with no issues, and it downloads fine afterwards.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34725/discussion-between-martijn-van-put-and-teleute00)

Comment: Actually, the binaryreader change did fix it.  The zip file name was the same, though, and it wasn't overwriting - so I was just re-downloading the old, bad one and didn't realise it had been corrected.  Thanks!

Comment: Unable to find the namespace for "HttpStream"